# Accessible css Toggle

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have this Css Toggle which works as expected, I want to add the focus outline to all the toggles for accessiiblity

How do I add **tab focus Outline** to these toggles while tabbing ?

```css
.container {
  margin: 10px;
}

input.switch:empty {
  margin-left: -999px;
}

input.switch:empty~label {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  text-indent: 4em;
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input.switch:empty~label:before,
input.switch:empty~label:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: ' ';
  width: 3.6em;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

input.switch:empty~label:after {
  width: 1.4em;
  top: 0.1em;
  bottom: 0.1em;
  margin-left: 0.1em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgb(12, 12, 12), 1px 1px 5px black;
}

input.switch:checked~label:before {
  background-color: #aaf;
}

input.switch:checked~label:after {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

label:focus {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" name="switch1" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch1">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch2" name="switch2" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch2">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch3" name="switch3" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch3">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch4" name="switch4" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch4">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch5" name="switch5" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch5">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `input:focus` add outline to `label` or you can add border if you want to use `border-radius`

```
input.switch:empty:focus~label{
  outline:1px solid red;
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 10px;
}

input.switch:empty {
  margin-left: -999px;
}
input.switch:empty:focus~label{
  outline:1px solid red;
}
input.switch:empty~label {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  text-indent: 4em;
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input.switch:empty~label:before,
input.switch:empty~label:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: ' ';
  width: 3.6em;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

input.switch:empty~label:after {
  width: 1.4em;
  top: 0.1em;
  bottom: 0.1em;
  margin-left: 0.1em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgb(12, 12, 12), 1px 1px 5px black;
}

input.switch:checked~label:before {
  background-color: #aaf;
}

input.switch:checked~label:after {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

label:focus {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" name="switch1" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch1">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch2" name="switch2" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch2">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch3" name="switch3" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch3">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch4" name="switch4" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch4">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch5" name="switch5" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch5">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know we can use it on psuedo selectors.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you -

**1st Solution**

I have used

```
.switch:empty:focus~label:before {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 10px;
}

input.switch:empty {
  margin-left: -999px;
}

input.switch:empty~label {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  text-indent: 4em;
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input.switch:empty~label:before,
input.switch:empty~label:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: ' ';
  width: 3.6em;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

input.switch:empty~label:after {
  width: 1.4em;
  top: 0.1em;
  bottom: 0.1em;
  margin-left: 0.1em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgb(12, 12, 12), 1px 1px 5px black;
}

input.switch:checked~label:before {
  background-color: #aaf;
}

input.switch:checked~label:after {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

input.switch:empty:focus~label:before {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" name="switch1" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch1">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch2" name="switch2" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch2">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch3" name="switch3" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch3">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch4" name="switch4" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch4">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch5" name="switch5" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch5">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2nd Solution**

But in here I have used `: active`.

```css
.container{
    margin: 10px;
}

input.switch:empty{
        margin-left: -999px;
    }

    input.switch:empty ~ label
    {
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     line-height: 1.6em;
     text-indent: 4em;
     margin: 0.2em 0;
     cursor: pointer;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }

    input.switch:empty ~ label:before,
    input.switch:empty ~ label:after
    {
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     content: ' ';
     width: 3.6em;
     background-color: #ccc;
     -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
     transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        border-radius: 1em;
    }

    input.switch:empty ~ label:after
    {
     width: 1.4em;
     top: 0.1em;
     bottom: 0.1em;
     margin-left: 0.1em;
     background-color: #fff;
     border-radius: 1em;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgb(12, 12, 12), 1px 1px 5px black;
    }

    input.switch:checked ~ label:before
    {
     background-color: #aaf;
    }

    input.switch:checked ~ label:after
    {
        margin-left: 2em;
    }
    label:active:before{
        border:1px solid #000;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="custom-toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" name="switch1" class="switch" />
  <label for="switch1">Toggle</label>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="custom-toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch2" name="switch2" class="switch" />
  <label for="switch2">Toggle</label>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="custom-toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch3" name="switch3" class="switch" />
  <label for="switch3">Toggle</label>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="custom-toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch4" name="switch4" class="switch" />
  <label for="switch4">Toggle</label>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="custom-toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch5" name="switch5" class="switch" />
  <label for="switch5">Toggle</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Check if this is what you need.Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 2nd solution doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @bhansa it works only on clicking on the toggle. if you want to see just long click on the toggle.!

Answer (score 1):

Add this css:

```
 input.switch:focus:empty ~ label::before {
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```css
input.switch:focus:empty ~ label::before {
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}

.container {
  margin: 10px;
}

input.switch:empty {
  margin-left: -999px;
}

input.switch:empty~label {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  text-indent: 4em;
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input.switch:empty~label:before,
input.switch:empty~label:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: ' ';
  width: 3.6em;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

input.switch:empty~label:after {
  width: 1.4em;
  top: 0.1em;
  bottom: 0.1em;
  margin-left: 0.1em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgb(12, 12, 12), 1px 1px 5px black;
}

input.switch:checked~label:before {
  background-color: #aaf;
}

input.switch:checked~label:after {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

label:focus {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" name="switch1" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch1">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch2" name="switch2" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch2">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch3" name="switch3" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch3">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch4" name="switch4" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch4">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch5" name="switch5" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch5">Toggle</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code in your css:

```
input.switch:checked ~ label:focus:before {
    outline: 2px solid rgb(247, 0, 220);
}
input.switch:checked ~ label:before {
    border: 2px solid rgba(236, 180, 230, 0.72);
}
```